# How can I get the change event to fire on a select control when binding in AngularJS?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to listen for the jquery change event when Angular binds to a select control. However, the change event is not fired and I can't figure out why. Here is a jsFiddle example that shows the problem (uses onchange to avoid timing issues):

http://jsfiddle.net/tSkuw/1/

Here's the HTML...

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    Hello, {{test.day}}!<br>
    <select id="selDay" ng-model="test.day" onchange="logSelChange()">
        <option value="">Select Day</option>
        <option value="MON">Monday</option>
        <option value="TUE">Tuesday</option>
        <option value="WED">Wednesday</option>
        <option value="THU">Thursday</option>
        <option value="FRI">Friday</option>
        <option value="SAT">Saturday</option>
        <option value="SUN">Sunday</option>
    </select>
    <div id="divLog"></div>
</div>
```

And here's the JS...

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.test = {
        day: 'TUE'
    };
}

function logSelChange() {
    $('#divLog').append('<div>Changed to ' + $('#selDay').val() + '</div>');
}
```

The change message is displayed if you change the select box, but it is not displayed when Angular binds to the control. How can I get Angular to fire the change event after it binds to the control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I combined the answers from @dimirc and @CodeHater and came up with the following directive...

http://jsfiddle.net/cyf8p/4/

```
myApp.directive('myCombo', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var $el = $(element);

            // Make sure the value gets initialized correctly.
            $timeout(function () {
                $el.change();
            });

            // Make sure the value gets updated when the model changes.
            if (attrs.ngModel) {
                scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function () {
                    $timeout(function() {
                        $el.change();
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

And it is applied like so...

```
<select id="selDay" ng-model="test.day" my-combo>
```

This does cause the change event to be raised twice when you change the value from the control, but it ensures the change event is raised whenever it is modified.

Answer (score 0):

You can give time for current cycle to finish with bindings. $timeout will do the trick

```
    $timeout(function(){logSelChange()});
```

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/AbRQ6/

Answer (score 0):

You should not generally do anything outside Angular's scope. To make it an Angular app fully, I have made these changes: Use `ngOptions` to create the select's options and `$watch` to fire the callback whenever `test.day` changes:

### HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    Hello, {{test.day}}!<br>
    <select id="selDay" ng-model="test.day" ng-options="obj.day as obj.dayName 
    for obj in days">
        <option value="">Select Day</option>        
    </select>
    <div id="divLog"></div>
</div>
```

### Controller

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.days = [
        {day:"MON",dayName:"Monday"},
        {day:"TUE",dayName:"Tuesday"},
        {day:"WED",dayName:"Wednesday"},
        {day:"THU",dayName:"Thursday"},
        {day:"FRI",dayName:"Friday"},
        {day:"SAT",dayName:"Saturday"},
        {day:"SUN",dayName:"Sunday"}
    ];
    
    $scope.test = {
        day: 'TUE'
    };
    
    /* fire the callback whenever 'test.day' changes */
    $scope.$watch("test.day",function(){            
        $('#divLog').append('<div>Changed to ' + $scope.test.day + '</div>');
    });
}
```

Angular also has a `ngChange` directive that you can use in place of onchange.

Comment: The control is built using a jQuery plugin in order to style it (the select control isn't visible to the user). It requires the change event to be raised in order to keep the value synchronized with the display.